# How to get the onClick function?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make a scientific calculator inside a fragment. Actually following a YT video and that guy is doing all that in his mainactivity not the fragment. I used this code in xml of my fragment:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scientific_calculator, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    previousCalculation = view.findViewById(R.id.previousCalculationView);
    display = view.findViewById(R.id.displayEditText);

}

private void updateText(String strTOAdd) {
    display.setText(strTOAdd);
}

public void zeroBTNPush(View view) {
    updateText("0");
}
```

All I know is that to use findViewById in a fragment, I have to create a onViewCreated void. So after doing all this I should get the updateText function in fragment.java>design>attributes>onClick but I get nothing there
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwWFo.jpg)
I'm new to this. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can just set OnClickListener in your fragment code like this

```
someBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    // call the method you want to be excecuted when the buttun is being pressed
})
```

also you can specify it in the design, but for example I would prefer to work with the XML code directly - it's much more understantable for me

Comment: let me try to do that

Comment: where should I enter that onClickListner?

Comment: display.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListner() {
  // do the stuff here
})

Answer (score 0):

To use `findViewById` I think all you need is a `View` object, which is returned by `onCreateView`, so you could just do:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scientific_calculator, container, false);
    Button btn = view.findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId); 
    btn.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
        // do something here
    });
}
```

Comment: there is no view there so I can't type view.findViewByID

Comment: you can if you do `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scientific_calculator, container, false);` insteead of `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scientific_calculator, container, false);` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `onViewCreated` with the view that is passed in by getting the button and setting a click listener on it like this:

```java
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    //...

    Button myButton = view.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
        // do button stuff
    });
}
```